# chmod doesn't work on folder 'd --- --- ---' permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

In `/var/www` I've got a folder:

```
d--------- 2 www-data www-data  4096 May 20  2012 update
```

reported by `ls -la`.

I'm logged in as root, but I can't change permissions or ownership. `chown` and `chmod` returns 'Operation not permitted'

An automatic update procedure demands all files and folders to be owned by 'www-data' and permissions set to 'u+w'.

Comment: SELinux, AppArmor or similar active? Have a look at `dmesg | tail -n 20` immediately after the `chown`/`chmod` call. It may be a good idea to run `fsck` on that filesystem. Is that directory a mount point?

Comment: Try `lsattr` on it as well to see if the immutable bit is set. Is it a mountpoint for a special kind of filesystem?

Comment: Yep, lsattr reports the immutable bit is set.

Comment: Depending on why that bits set, `sudo chattr -i /var/www/update` will turn it off, but ask yourself why is that bit set in the first place?

Comment: @slm Please post that as an answer. Right now the question is sitting on the unanswered list, but it isn't *really* unanswered.

Comment: Is www a read-only mounted partition ? Try `mount`.

Answer (score 3):

As I searched through the list of unanswered questions for ones that I might be able to answer, I saw this question’s title and I figured that it might be an issue with file attributes. As detailed in the question’s comments, the **immutable attribute** had been set and @slm posted the solution:

```
sudo chattr -i /var/www/update
```

However, @slm also asked a very pertinent question, *“why is that bit set in the first place?”* The first time I learned of the immutable bit was when I was asked to look at a server that had been rooted. The binaries for `ps` and `lsof` had been replaced with modified versions (in order to hide other malicious processes) and the immutable bit had been set to prevent any future OS updates from replacing the malicious executables with updated genuine versions.